# How to update the network name (SSID) on the network adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My LAN adapter shows the name of my WLAN (SSID), which is very confusing. This happened during setting up a WLAN extender.

Is there a possibility to update/refresh this name?

Windows:

[image]

Router:

[image]

Comment: What do ypu want/expect to happen? Change the SSID on your router?

Comment: @davidgo I would prefer to have no name showing up there instead of one of the WLAN names. I additionally have the 2.4GHz access active on the router, so the next confusing thing is, why is the 5GHz name chosen instead of the 2.4GHz name.

Comment: What you are saying about "no name" does not make sense to me.

Comment: @davidgo I just want **not** the name of a random WLAN Access point (the router has 2 for different Hz, additionally Guest accesspoints to both, so 4 access points in total). Because it appears that something is configured wrongly, because I am connected with a LAN cable.

Comment: Ah, that's a Windows-specific thing where it detects the network name by seeing that the gateway has the same MAC address as it had when you connected via Wi-Fi earlier. Ethernet connections themselves have no "SSIDs" or anything like that.

Comment: @user1686 Ok, would it be possible to customize the network name on Windows for this Network adapter, without altering the Accesspoint names on the router?